# tpope's cucumber.vim steps files warnings

Tags: vim, cucumber

I get this warning in step files on every Given, Then, When line:

```
ambiguous first argument; put parentheses or even spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

update ruby itself, rake and your gems. I get this error too, some month ago. It was not an rspec or cucumber error.